# Python daemon for reading a specific content from one log file and writing it to other

Tags: python, cron, cron-task, python-daemon, python-watchdog

I need to create a python daemon which is running in a background that should be responsible for reading a content from one log file(consider a.log) and needs to write it to another file(consider b.log).

That is whenever a file(a.log) is getting a particular phrase then corresponding entry should be made to a another file(b.log).

I hope it is clear, Anyone help me with it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? To watch the log file `a.log` for changes (on filesystem) you could consider using the [watchdog module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) and look for the desired phrase using a appropriate regex each time `a.log` was changed.

Comment: Which system are you working on? If working on Unix-based machines and if finding your phrase is not time-critical you could think about using a cron jobbed python script which is run every let's say two minutes checking the whole `a.log` for the desired phrase and copy it to `b.log` if found. However, the best way would be to interfere with the logging itself and write the desired log message to `a.log` as well as to `b.log`.

Comment: Thank you @albert, Actually now I have created a codes for reading a log file and inserting entry in to another file, If match is found. And I am using Unix based environment.

Comment: So could you please edit your question and provide the code you've written so far? As far as I understand, your problem is not to find the phrase but to automatically do this, isnt' it?

Comment: Ya, I need to make it in a automated way, That is whenever log file is getting a particular content, another file should be updated.

Comment: As I mentioned above there are several ways to do this. If you have to do it somehow live or on-line you could think about the [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) module or use a periodically executed [cron job](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) if live or on-line recognition does not matter.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will consider using Watchdog Module.

Comment: If you solved your question later on please provide your solution as an answer and mark your question as solved.